# WebGL Rotating cube overriding faces

Tags: javascript, webgl, cube

I am creating a simple WebGL program that creates a cube rotating around the Z axis. The problem is that when its rotating some sides of it override the others and you don't see each individual side of the cube. I looked for a solution online but it makes it worse. They enable the face culling and for them, it seems to work but for me, unfortunately, it doesn't. Can anyone tell me what do I need to add into my code in order to fix the face overriding?

Full Source Code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
var a = 24;
var positions = [
  -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
  0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
  0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
  -0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
  -0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
  0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
  0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
  -0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
  //0.5, 0.5, 1.0,
];

var indices = [
  0, 1, 2,  0, 2, 3, // Front
  0, 4, 7,  0, 3, 7, // Side 1
  1, 5, 6,  1, 2, 6, // Side 2
  4, 5, 6,  6, 7, 4  // Back
];

var rotation_angle = 1;
var radians = (rotation_angle * Math.PI)/180;
var rotation = [Math.sin(radians), 0.0, Math.cos(radians)];

var _buffer = gl.createBuffer();
var i_buffer = gl.createBuffer();

var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, `
precision mediump float;
attribute vec3 position;
uniform vec3 rotation;

varying vec3 f_col;


void main(){

  vec2 newPos = vec2(
    position.x * rotation.x - position.z * rotation.z,

    position.x * rotation.z + position.z * rotation.x
  );
  gl_Position = vec4(newPos.x, position.y, newPos.y, 1.0);
  f_col = position;
}
`);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

// Check if it compiled

var success2 = gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
if (!success2) {
  // Something went wrong during compilation; get the error
  throw "could not compile shader:" + gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader);
}

var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, `
precision mediump float;
varying vec3 f_col;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(f_col.x, 0.2, f_col.z, 1.0);
}
`);

gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

var success1 = gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
if (!success1) {
  // Something went wrong during compilation; get the error
  throw "could not compile shader:" + gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader);
}

var program = gl.createProgram();

// Attach pre-existing shaders
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);

var attributeLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "position");
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, _buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), 
gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(attributeLoc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attributeLoc);
gl.useProgram(program);

var rotation_location = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "rotation");

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, i_buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), 
gl.STATIC_DRAW);

function loop() {
  gl.clearColor(0.75, 0.85, 0.8, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  //gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 8);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, a, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  //gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 1, 3);
  rotation_angle++;
  var radians = (rotation_angle * Math.PI)/180;
  var rotation = [Math.sin(radians), 0.0, Math.cos(radians)];

  gl.uniform3fv(rotation_location, rotation);
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

loop();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Enable depth testing: `gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);`

Comment: where in the code should I enable it or it doesnt matter?

Comment: @ПламенЦанев OpenGL is a state engine, so once the [depth test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) is enabled it is kept enabled. Do `gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);` somewhere before `loop();`.